# Multidimensional array sort from high to low using numerical values found in array

Tags: php

I am currently looking for an efficient way to sort an array/object based on highest -> lowest using `avgTotalPoints` and then placing a numerical value accoring to rank in `rank` field. I looked at some examples and was able to create a function accordingly. However, it is now working. I am trying to access `avgTotalPoints` in the sort function shown below but I am unable because the array is multi depth. Any guidance in how to accomplish this?

```
function sortHighestToLowest($arr)
{
    if (isset($arr) && !empty($arr)) {
        uasort($arr, function ($a, $b) {
            return $a['avgTotalPoints'] <=> $b['avgTotalPoints'];
        });
        return array_reverse($arr);
    }
    return null;
}
```

JSON Input

```
{
    "mlb": {
        "james": {
            "avgTotalPoints": 80.675,
            "avgPointsDifferential": -0.8112500000000002,
            "rank": null
        },
        "mary": {
            "avgTotalPoints": 114.9875,
            "avgPointsDifferential": 6.262500000000003,
            "rank": null
        },
        "lucas": {
            "avgTotalPoints": 66.825,
            "avgPointsDifferential": -9.10625,
            "rank": null
        },
        "timothy": {
            "avgTotalPoints": 69.2625,
            "avgPointsDifferential": -19.14125,
            "rank": null
        },
        "samantha": {
            "avgTotalPoints": 91.625,
            "avgPointsDifferential": -36.85000000000001,
            "rank": null
        }
    },
    "nhl": {
        "samantha": {
            "avgTotalPoints": 82.20000000000002,
            "avgPointsDifferential": 15.005714285714289,
            "rank": null
        },
        "peter": {
            "avgTotalPoints": 77.65714285714284,
            "avgPointsDifferential": -13.31857142857143,
            "rank": null
        },
        "rick": {
            "avgTotalPoints": 91.61428571428571,
            "avgPointsDifferential": 11.217142857142859,
            "rank": null
        },
        "bubba": {
            "avgTotalPoints": 119.60000000000001,
            "avgPointsDifferential": 28.13333333333334,
            "rank": null
        },
        "james": {
            "avgTotalPoints": 90.18571428571428,
            "avgPointsDifferential": 10.915714285714285,
            "rank": null
        }
    }
}
```

Desired Result

````
stdClass Object
(
    [mlb] => stdClass Object
        (            
            [mary] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [avgTotalPoints] => 114.9875
                    [avgPointsDifferential] => 6.2625
                    [rank] => 1
                )
            
            [samantha] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [avgTotalPoints] => 91.625
                    [avgPointsDifferential] => -36.85
                    [rank] => 2
                )
                
            [james] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [avgTotalPoints] => 80.675
                    [avgPointsDifferential] => -0.81125
                    [rank] => 3
                )

            [timothy] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [avgTotalPoints] => 69.2625
                    [avgPointsDifferential] => -19.14125
                    [rank] => 4
                )

            [lucas] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [avgTotalPoints] => 66.825
                    [avgPointsDifferential] => -9.10625
                    [rank] => 5
                )

        )

    [nhl] => stdClass Object
        (
            [bubba] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [avgTotalPoints] => 119.6
                    [avgPointsDifferential] => 28.133333333333
                    [rank] => 1
                )
                
            [rick] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [avgTotalPoints] => 91.614285714286
                    [avgPointsDifferential] => 11.217142857143
                    [rank] => 2
                )

            [james] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [avgTotalPoints] => 90.185714285714
                    [avgPointsDifferential] => 10.915714285714
                    [rank] => 3
                )       
        
            [samantha] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [avgTotalPoints] => 82.2
                    [avgPointsDifferential] => 15.005714285714
                    [rank] => 4
                )

            [peter] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [avgTotalPoints] => 77.657142857143
                    [avgPointsDifferential] => -13.318571428571
                    [rank] => 5
                )

        )

)
```
````

Comment: What does the input array look like?

Comment: _Side note:_ Using both `isset()` and `!empty()` in the same if-condition is redundant. You can just use `!empty()` since that covers what `isset()` does as well.

Comment: @Jeto sorry, I now added the json input.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson oh good point. I was always confused about that. I will make that change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your array contains multiple subarrays that you want to sort separately, you could make use of [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/array_map) to apply the sorting to each of these subarrays.

After doing so, you could then simply loop over that same subarray (by reference) while incrementing a `$rank` variable, and assigning it to each entry.

Also, you don't need to use `array_reverse` to reverse the sorting, simply reverse the operands of your `<=>` comparison instead.

```
function sortHighestToLowest(array $arr): array
{
  return array_map(static function (array $entries): array {
    uasort($entries, static function (array $entry1, array $entry2): int {
      return $entry2['avgTotalPoints'] <=> $entry1['avgTotalPoints'];
    });

    $rank = 0;
    foreach ($entries as &$entry) {
      $entry['rank'] = ++$rank;
    }

    return $entries;
  }, $arr);
}
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/YXP3o)**

Comment: This is perfect. I was reading into `array_map` and was seeing how to use it!